# Storing cv2 images into cache or memory

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, opencv3.0

I'm currently doing some image processing using a 5 mega pixel camera. I'm converting the images from the camera in CV2 format using cpp. Afterwards I load them using Python script to process the images. The loading of 200 images requires 9.426 sec using cv2.imread() and the following code:

```
    images = glob.glob('InputSimulation\*.jpg')
    #images = Glob.fileList("InputSimulation"+os.sep)
    # images = images.sort()
    # sort out all characters just let the string remain
    images = sorted(images, key=lambda name: int(name[22:-4]))

    # TestNewMethod
    index = 0
    cv2ImageList = []
    for fname in images:
       #for testing reasons
        if index % skip_fac != 0:
            continue
        cv2ImageList.append(cv2.imread(fname))
```

I'm not sure if there is a faster way than using cv2.imread() and a for loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you are loading 100 **million** pixels per second, and you think that is slow?

Comment: Yes I do, because processing them is way faster. My computations run in 1.6 s for all images and I do fancy stuff. The only bottleneck is the storing of the images inside my memory (List).

Comment: So the question was is there a way to store the images in the ram on Windows 10 using a ram disk.

Comment: @MaxKrappmann Because you read your files from a hard disk or ssd. In code theres almost nothing you can do to speed this up.

Comment: @Hafnernuss yes I'm currently reading from my ssd.